# Cannot open new tab from command line anymore with Firefox 61

Tags: command-line, firefox, browser, process, browser-tabs

Recently switched to Firefox 61, any attempt to open a new tab from the command line with

```
firefox http://pretty.much/anything
```

hangs.. then fails with the **"Firefox is already running but is not responding."** message.

I have tried deactivating a few weird plugins (*e.g.* tridactyl) and restarting ff with no success.

I can see plenty of topics out there regarding this very error message, but they all address the problem of firefox not wanting to be clicked open.

In my case, firefox *is* already open (and looks fine), but I cannot add a `--new-tab` or a `--new-window` to it from command line anymore.

What could be the problem?

Comment: But it works in my PC. Did you change any settings or in `about:config`?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Not much. However, if I sort by `Status` I can see that many have been `modified` indeed, probably by the extensions? What option category do you think would be relevant for this issue? (like `browser.tabs` or `services`?)

Comment: @Biswapriyo Maybe interesting to note: this whole firefox version is locally installed in my `/opt` folder. However, I can check with `ps aux | grep firefox` and `which firefox` that the right (same) binary is both currentyl being run *and* called by my `firefox --new-tab` command.

Comment: @Biswapriyo cheers :)